# my int thinks its a double, how do i change this?

Tags: c#, integer, double

im using an online compiler so maybe thats the reason that its not working.

so i set the TCoins int to 0

`int TCoins = 0;`

then after you defeat an enemy it adds to the int

`TCoins = coins + TCoins;`

then i made a shop system, so i check to see if you have the coin amount to be able to buy the item, then i subtract the coin amount needed to the coin amount you have, now for some reason it thinks its a double when i do this

```
if(Answer == "S" && TCoins >= (S + 1) * Math.Pow(10,(S+1)))
{
    TCoins = TCoins - (S + 1) * Math.Pow(10,(S+1));
    S++;
}
```

im new to coding, so i might be being dumb and not realising what the problem is.

Comment: `Math.Pow(10,(S+1))` returns `double`

Comment: `Math.Pow` returns a double. You can cast that back to an int if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Math` works with `double` and thus

```
Math.Pow(10,(S+1));
```

returns `double` result (for instance, if `S == -2` we'll get `0.1`). You can either *cast*:

`(int) Math.Pow(10,(S+1))`

or implement custom integer power:

```
public static class MathI {
  public static int Pow10(int value) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 9)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));

    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i)
      result *= 10;

    return result;
  }
}
```

And then use `MathI.Pow10(S + 1)` instead of `Math.Pow(10,S+1)`